# Using PHP/SQL to select, then delete image files that aren't referenced in user table

Tags: mysql

I have a site with user profiles. I've delete a slew of profiles within phpmyadmin, but those profiles that I've deleted still have their picture files in a folder on the website.

I'm looking for a script that I could run that would select/delete all the pictures in the folder that are not associated with any existing profile in the database.

A typical image name is like this: 0ae71e1bc25cae7e243464adb.jpg

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I'm not a major expert at using mysql operations for something of this nature.

So in an attempt to be more clear:

- I have let's say 100 existing users with their info in the database, including their profile picture name.
- Their profile picture is in a folder on the server called images
- In that same folder are images of users that do not exist
- I'd like to run a script that will check to see if that image is referenced in the "users" table by any user, and if not, delete it.

Your help us appreciated.

Comment: See JOINs. Specifically, LEFT JOINs

Answer (score 0):

I think this script should do the trick.

```
// Query the images paths as array using mysqli
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "foo_db"); 
$result = $db->query("SELECT image_path FROM users");    
$images_db = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Use glob to retrieve all the existing img in dir
$directory = "/home/user/public_html/images/";
$images_dir = glob($directory . "*.*");

// if image_dir is not in images_db delete it using unlink fn
foreach($images_dir as $image_dir) {
  if (!in_array($image_dir, $images_db)) {
   unlink($directory . $image_dir);
  }
}
```

You have to tweak the script for your need.
Be carefull with unlink ! First test the script in local !

Answer (score 0):

Lighter on memory solution:

```
$files = scandir(DIR_TO_IMAGES_FOLDER);
$db_conn = create_db_connection(); //assume this creates the connection to your db and return false if it cant;
if (!$db_conn) exit(); //no connection
foreach ($files as $file){
  if (is_file($file)){
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM TABLE_NAME
                WHERE image_name=:image_name";
      $result = $db_conn->prepare($query);
      $result->bindParam(":image_name", $file);
      $in_use = true; //assume it is in use just incase sql execute fails;
      try{
        $result->execute();
        $in_use = $result->fetchColumn();
      }catch (Exception $e){

      }

      if (!$in_use) unlink(DIR_TO_IMAGES_FOLDER . '/' . $file);
  }
}
```

But I would just create a new TABLE image_delete_pending and a trigger BEFORE DELETE on your 'users' table.  The trigger would insert the image_name to the image_delete_pending TABLE. Then the script will for sure know that every image in the image_delete_pending needs to be deleted.

The script would then be:

```
$db_conn = create_db_connection(); //assume this creates the connection to your db and return false if it cant;
if (!$db_conn) exit(); //end script; no connection

$query = "SELECT image_name
          FROM image_delete_pending;";
try{

    $result = $db_conn->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()){
         if(unlink(DIR_TO_IMAGES_FOLDER . '/' . $row['image_name'])){
            $db_conn->query("DELETE FROM image_delete_pending WHERE image_name='". $row['image_name'] ."';";
         }

    }

}catch (Exception $e){

}
```

Comment: Assuming there is 100 images. You're making 100 sql query instead of one. Another thing, glob is better than scandir because you can add a regex and retrieve image only.

Comment: yes, he can apply limit 0, X at a time if he wishes and don't really need to compare anything if he designs a table with images to be deleted.